# Error on : Publishing InfoPath forms to the SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm trying to publish Browser Enabled Infopath Forms to the SharePoint sever but, at the end it was showing me the following Error:

> The SOAP response indicates that an
>   error occurred on the server:
>
> ```
> Server was unable to process request. ---> Method 'get_ServerInfo'
> ```
>
> in type
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.XmlFormProxy'
>   from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' does
>   not have an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Infopath 2010 installed?

> WORK-AROUND: The issue appears to be associated to having the new Office 2010 beta products installed and specifically InfoPath 2010. I am investigating the assembly conflict but the easiest work-around for now is to simply uninstall InfoPath 2010 (beta) and re-run psconfig again (you should not need to uninstall any other 2010 beta product and this will likely be a non-issue at RTM).

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/tmathis/default.aspx)

Comment: No. I haven't installed infopath 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be also an issue with Office 2010 RTM. I just experienced the exact same problems using office 2010 installed on a fully patched MOSS 2007 farm.