# Error Publishing Infopath form to MOSS 2007 Site

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm currently tryign to get Infopath form services working on our farm however am running into a problem.

Doing some homework I found this thread:
[Error on : Publishing InfoPath forms to the SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299595)

Unfortunatly there is no date, but we are currently fully patched up to the latest CU and have infopath 2010 RTM installed on the web front end server (a neccessity for one of our farm features).

We recieve a generic error from Central Admin when we attempt to upload the form template to infopath server:

```
Method 'get_ServerInfo' in type 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.XmlFormProxy' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' does not have an implementation.
```

Has anyone run into this before and/or found a solution? We are attempting to get a very basic infopath 2007 web form template uploaded (made it in infopath 2010 and saved it with the compatibility flags set for 2007 web forms).

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue with Infopath 2010. You will need to uninstall and install 2007 version:
[Error on : Publishing InfoPath forms to the SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299595/error-on-publishing-infopath-forms-to-the-sharepoint-site)